# create a curve on top of a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath

i need to create a curve on top and bottom of a UIView, i used the following for the bottom :

```
 func pathCurvedForView(givenView: UIView, curvedPercent:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
        {
            let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
            arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
            arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))
            arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:givenView.bounds.size.height))
            arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:givenView.bounds.size.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width/2, y:givenView.bounds.size.height-givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent))
            arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
            arrowPath.close()
            
            return arrowPath
        }

    func applyCurvedPath(givenView: UIView,curvedPercent:CGFloat) {
        guard curvedPercent <= 1 && curvedPercent >= 0 else{
            return
        }
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: givenView.layer)
        shapeLayer.path = self.pathCurvedForView(givenView: givenView,curvedPercent: curvedPercent).cgPath
        shapeLayer.frame = givenView.bounds
        shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
        givenView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
```

it worked fine, but did only the job for the bottom of the view, any idea how to implement it for the topView?
thanks
[image]

Comment: Replace `arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))` with `arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width/2, y:givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent))`

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain the effect :

```
A             B
 + -------- +
 |          |
 |          |
 + -------- +
D            C
```

We want:

- Start at A (0,0): `move(to:)`
- Curve up to B (width, 0): `addQuadCurve(to:controlPoint:)`
- Straight to C (width, height): `addLine(to:)`
- Curve to D (0, height):  `addQuadCurve(to:controlPoint:)`
- Straight to A (0,0): `addLine(to:)`
- Close.

So replace

```
arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))
```

with

```
arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: givenView.bounds.size.width, y: 0), 
                       controlPoint: CGPoint(x: givenView.bounds.size.width/2, 
                                             y: givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent))
```